# When I try to install PySimpleGUI (4.53.0) in jupyter notebook using Python 3.8 the error "no module named 'PySimpleGUI' is returned

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pysimplegui, easygui

I have already used pip install pysimplegui, using pip list shows that it is installed in Terminal (I use a mac). I also made sure it was the most recent version of pysimplegui.

I'm newer to coding some I'm not sure what other information to put here. Any advice would be enormously helpful. I am using Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda.

I should add that before this I tried doing the same thing with easygui and had the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

In the anaconda terminal use `python -m pip install PySimpleGUI` so you install it in the python being used.

Comment: Just tried that and received the following:  python -m pip install PySimpleGUI
Requirement already satisfied: PySimpleGUI in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.53.0)
Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have solved the problem, thank you though.

Comment: If already installed, you'll need to add the upgrade parm: `python -m pip install --upgrade PySimpleGUI`

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `pip install` and `conda install` is not to recommend, although sometimes unavoidable. What has happened in your case is not related to this conflict, though. In this case, the wrong `pip` was invoked when installing the package, so it was installed for a different python interpreter than the one you're using to run the notebook. You can have several python versions installed globally, both python(2) and python3. Furthermore, you may have even more versions of python in virtual environments, so you need to pay attention to which version you want to install a package for.

In case you don't have any specific reason not to, you'll save yourself some future headaches by using the conda package management system over `pip` to avoid those situations where they don't play nice with each other and you end up with a broken or unpredictable package setup.

Note that I'm not saying `conda` is better than `pip` in any way, I'm only proposing going with `conda` since you're using the `Anaconda` environment and its preinstalled packages already.

Comment: Thanks! I uninstalled using pip and then installed using conda to see if it would help, and then got this: "Verifying transaction: | WARNING conda.core.path_actions:verify(962): Unable to create environments file. Path not writable.
  environment location: /Users/jnakata/.conda/environments.txt."  Would you happen to have any knowledge about this message?

Comment: Seems like a permission error. Check the permissions of the `.conda` dir and `environments.txt` and update them accordingly if your user does not have the required permissions to edit them. It's only a warning, though, so I'd expect the package is already installed and available for import

Answer (score 0):

copy from PySimpleGUI

https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Warning - tkinter + Python 3.7.3 and later, including 3.8 has problems
The version of tkinter that is being supplied with the 3.7.3 and later versions of Python is known to have a problem with table colors. Basically, they don't work. As a result, if you want to use the plain PySimpleGUI running on tkinter, you should be using 3.7.2 or less. 3.6 is the version PySimpleGUI has chosen as the recommended version for most users.